# Withdrawal of provident fund

Tags: india, retirement-plan, income-tax-refund

It has been one year I've worked with an multi-national company and now I am quitting my job and flying abroad. I want to close my provident fund account and get the money credited to me. What is the procedure?

And I'll be leaving India in a month. So is there any way that my friend or any family member take care of the procedure to close my provident fund or is there any online process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to file an application with [PF Office](http://www.epfindia.com/site_en/WhichClaimForm.php#Q3). Normally your existing Organisation [which you just quit] helps you with the formalities. If not you would have to complete the same and submit it to the EPFO.